# experiences with Intersoft ClientUI?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, devforce

Somebody has experience using this wpf control library?

[clientui](http://www.clientui.com) from intersoft company

- service support?
- memory consumption?
- quality of controls?
- controls customizations?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have been using ClientUI controls since October 2010 for both WPF and Sliverlight apps. One of the best features about the controls is the fact that MVVM is built into the controls and it makes building a MVVM app very easy. I Found that I can build an MVVM app with just ClientUI and Ideablade for the entity manager and I don't need a MVVM framework. The level of support is excellent. I may have waited just under a day for an response. They have lots of tutorials, examples, great documentation, and a good forum. They also come out with updates frequently and they have great plans for the future of the product. Since the controls are built using MVVM princiles and since they are adhere to good programming proinciples, it is easy to add on to the controls and customize them. Since using the controls, I have gotten rid of all my other controls in the toolbox. i have had no memory issues. I am not an employee of the company. I am a developer who owns a small consulting firm and feels that these controls are the best controls out there for WPF and Silverlight.